Axler Measure Theory - Question about proof of 3.11
I'm reading Sheldon Axler's Measure, Integration & Real Analysis book and have a question.
In the proof of the inequality in the other direction, why is $t \in (0, 1)$ introduced here? What if we remove $t$ from the definition of $E_k$? Will it still work?

The image is from Sheldon Axler. Measure, Integration & Real Analysis, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Springer, 2020.

It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Would you please elaborate which specific steps confuse you? Even if you think many steps of implication are not clear to you, it is better to type out them one by one than simply putting "the second part of this proof which starts with 'To prove the inequality in the other direction' ".

I just edited the question with the step that confuses me.

No, without the $t$ the proof doesn’t work. In fact $E_k$ might be empty for every $k$ if you didn’t have the $t$.

So $t$ will automatically fit the in the condition so that $E_k$ is nonempty?

Since the comment section is already long, I write a short answer here.
The role of $t$ is essential. Take the case where we have $f = 1$ and $f_k = \frac{k}{k+1}$, then $f_k(x) \rightarrow f(x), \forall x \in X$. Take $A_1 = X$, so the simple function on the right hand side of (3.12) in the picture is just $g = 1_X$, the sets $E_k = \{x \in E: f_k(x) \geq 1 \}$ (with $t$ removed) is empty for any $k$ and thus the union of $(E_k)$ cannot be $X$. The important of $t \in (0,1)$ is to make sure the union of the sets $(E_k)$ is $X$.
If $t \in (0,1)$ appears again in the definition $E_k = \{x \in E: f_k(x) \geq t \}$, then you can see that $E_k$ would be nonempty for $k$ big enough (and from that on, $E_k = X$).
